# Aurelia mapping to razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, aurelia

I've probably just done something dumb, but indulge me?

Say I have this Aurelia viewmodel -

```
import { useView } from "aurelia-framework";

@useView("/LandingPartials/Intro")
export class Intro {
}
```

And this MVC controller method

```
public ActionResult Intro()
{
    return View("IntroPartial");
}
```

And this Razor view (currently without anything dynamic, just for testing)

```
<template>
    <section id="intro" class="intro">
        <div class="slogan">
            <h2>
                <span class="text_color">Something Something</span>
            </h2>
            <h4>Something something something profit?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="page-scroll">
            <a href="#services" class="btn btn-circle">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

And everything's being called correctly and seems okay, why do I get the following error message?

```
Template markup must be wrapped in a <template> element
```

It's driving me mad (and ruining my pitch to get my company to go Aurelia over React).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind, found it.  The problem was the _ViewStart.cshtml partial.

I removed the content from it - since I'm using custom layouts anyway - and suddenly, everything is fine.

As I said, something dumb.  I'll leave this question here, though.  In case anyone else has a moment and does the same dumb thing.